# How i can serialize value of class field

Tags: c#

I have program when i have Serializable class. This class contain object with unique ID (p.1, p.2, p.3 etc.) but when i restart the program, Derialize objects of this class and try to create new object it get again initial number of ID and i have two objects with the same ID.

Fields of ID looks like below:

```
private static int numer;
private string lp;
```

Constructor of this class do something like:

```
this.lp = $"P.{numer.ToString()}";
numer++;
```

What i should do to get next number when creating new objects after restarting program?

EDIT:
Code of the class:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Pielegniarka : Osoba
{
    private string funkcja;
    private static int numer;
    private string lp;
    private int dyzury;
    public Pielegniarka(string noweImie, string noweNazwisko, string nowyPesel) : base(noweImie, noweNazwisko, nowyPesel)
    {
        this.lp = $"P.{numer.ToString()}";
        this.funkcja = "pielegniarka";
        numer++;
    }
```

EDIT 2:
Deserialize method:

```
public static ListaOsob Deserializuj()
        {
            ListaOsob ls = new ListaOsob();
            BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            if (File.Exists(@"C:\szpital\ludzie.dat"))
            {
                using (Stream fStream = new FileStream(@"C:\szpital\ludzie.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    ls = (ListaOsob)binFormatter.Deserialize(fStream);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                List<Osoba> personsList = new List<Osoba>();
                ls.Listaludzi = personsList;
            }
            return ls;
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "Program", is that kind of EXE or something?

Comment: After you deserialize your classes, you'll need to set the next id.  Are you doing that?

Comment: `numer` is reset to 0 after you start again. You can mitigate the problem by a) using GUIDs or b) increment `numer` as long as the created name already exists. or c) get `numer` from a db (like for example a sequence in SQL Server...) or just serialize the last value of numer along with the objects on app exit and read it back on app start.

Comment: You'll need to keep track of `numer` externally to the program and update it every time you create a new instance of the class. A database is the most common way of doing this, but a text file or any number of other methods are available.

Comment: @SelimYıldız it as simple c# application

Comment: @Amy I not sure how to do that

Comment: @Cisiur Well since you didn't share any of that with us, we can't help you with that.

Comment: @Amy I'm not sure what i should add more. Sorry i'm just beginner in programming :(

Comment: @Cisiur Add your code to the question.  We can't help with code we can't see.

Comment: @Amy i added code of the class to the question.

Comment: We also need to see the code where you deserialize your classes

Comment: Just as a side comment: as a non-English native speaker I know how tempting it can be to use non-English words to define models, methods, variables, projects etc., but it is a bad idea in 99.99%. I would strongly recommend to start using English words.

Comment: @Amy thats added now

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I'll try to do it in next project